# Get full site clone

Tags: html, linux, unix, apache2, web-crawler

Is there a way to crawl a website and have it download every single file and make it relative? I have a site that has a lot of absolute url's and when I use wget it only downloads the index.html page and doesn't get the files that are absolute urls nor does it turn them into relative links. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: you can tell wget with `-p` to load prerequisites

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a programming question ... but you could try [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

Its free and open source and available on both windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Firefox extension called [DownloadThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) that can crawl for sure a single page. Not sure if you can force it to crawl an entire website.

Answer (score -1):

Httrak is a decent cloning free app, be it a .com or .onion  You have to change proxies and a few tweaks, cant fully remember now, you can find the relevant info on YouTube.  Yet if a non DW site, can download all files using Httrak.

Comment: At least post a link? This answer doesn't give much information to work with